# What data backup software provides these specific features?

Tags: windows, backup, ftp, sftp

I'm looking for data backup software (one license for use on my home machine running Windows 7) with the following features specifically:

- ability to select individual files and directories for backup (and to save such sets to individual profiles)
- ideally, ability to include/exclude files based on filename or even content filters
- incremental only-as-needed updates to backed-up data (i.e. progressive backups)
- ability to store multiple timestamped versions of some or all directories (similar to Mac's "Time Machine")
- ability to back up data to multiple locations concurrently
- either

  - ability to encrypt data and store on a server I control via FTP (I am not interested in cloud services at the moment)
  - ability to store data on a server I control via SFTP
- preferably $150 USD or less

The amount of data I'm looking to back up is very modest (< 1 GB) and the amount of data that changes from update to update would be small (< 1 MB). My ideal setup would be to configure the software once to specify exactly what I do and don't want backed up, and then have a one-click solution that performs an incremental, timestamped update to the backup on demand. The data would be concurrently backed up on two external HDs and on a server I control.

Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: OT: Can you develop software and would you be interested in developing such a program?

Comment: @Thomas - I can develop software, but unfortunately my plate is too full right now to take on any new projects.

Answer (score 3):

You check out [CloudBerry Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup), from a company I am affiliated with, to automate Windows Server backup to Amazon S3 ,  Glacier, Google Cloud Storage , MS Azure and 20 more cloud storage providers.  It comes with the following features:

1. Scheduling and Real-Time Cloud Backup
2. Comes with one time fee and no recurring charges.
3. No proprietary data format and you can access your data using other Amazon s3 tools.
4. Supports all Amazon S3 regions and Reduced Redundancy Storage.
5. Amazon Glacier support
6. Encryption & Compression
7. Local Backup
8. Incremental and Block Level Backup
9. Network Locations Backup

15 day free trial is available http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup

We even have a FREE version limited to 200GB and no compression / encryption